# Как прочитать содержимое файла .xlsx с помощью python?

Tags: python, файлы, excel

Дано: файл Excel (.xlsx)
В файле одним столбцом в 120 строк записаны текстовые данные
Надо: прочитать файл средствами python, получив список строковых переменных из строк файла.

Comment: [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Как создать [mcve]?

Comment: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Answer (score 2):

Алгоритм действий:

1. устанавливаете модуль Pandas
2. читаете [документацию](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/10min.html)
3. читаете Excel файл в Pandas DataFrame, используя функцию [pd.read_excel()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)
4. выбираете нужный вам столбец из DataFrame и преобразуете его в список, используя метод [Series.to_list()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.tolist.html)

PS если у вас нет времени или желания сформулировать вопрос, согласно правилам ресурса SO и привести в вопросе собственные попытки решения данного вопроса - можно обратиться к профессионалам-фриленсерам за готовым решением;)

Comment: С использованием pandas это можно, конечно, сделать, но для такого простого действия можно обойтись и стандартными библиотеками python.

Comment: @Евгений., не подскажите - какой из __стандартных__ модулей Python умеет читать Excel файлы? ;)

Comment: @Евгений, ну так и покажите в своем вопросе, как вы обошлись стандартными библиотеками.

Comment: Мне вот тут MaxU как раз и предложил обратиться  к "профессионалам - фрилансерам". Извините, что обратился не туда.  Если хотите больше знать про стандартные библиотеки Python, опять же есть совет от MaxU - читайте документацию. Я пошёл читать документацию.

Comment: @Евгений., `"Я пошёл читать документацию."` - очень рад, что мы помогли вам прийти к этому непростому решению )